# Getting exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name ‘score’ available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I am sending a list of objects from controller method of spring mvc to thymeleaf view through model attribute and want to iterate the list in a view with table and i want to make each row a html form so that if i edit the row which represents the object in a list will update the object. But I am getting exception **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name ‘score’ available as request attribute.** Can anyone help me to find out What mistake I am doing?

Handler Method

```
@GetMapping("/exams/update")
    public String viewStudentUpdate(@RequestParam("subject") Integer id ,Model model)
    {
        Subject subject = serviceSubjectDao.getSubjectById(id);
        List<Score> scores = serviceScoreDao.getScoreForSubject(subject);

        model.addAttribute("scores",scores);
        model.addAttribute("subjectName",subject);
        model.addAttribute("PageName","StudentMarksUpdate");
        return "Template";
    }
```

Thymeleaf template

```
 <table class="m-2 table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
                <th scope="col">CT-1</th>
                <th scope="col">CT-2</th>
                <th scope="col">INTERNAL</th>
                <th scope="col">END SEMESTER</th>
                <th scope="col">GRADE</th>
                <th scope="col">EXAM DATE</th>
                <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-center">
            <tr th:each="score : ${scores}">
                <form th:action="@{/faculty/exams/update/process}" th:object="${score}" method="post">
                    <td th:text="${score.student.name}"><a th:href="@{/Student/profile/view(stId=${score.student.id})}" class="text-decoration-none">name</a></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="ct1" id="ct1" th:field="*{ct1}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="ct2" id="ct2" th:field="*{ct2}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="internal" id="internal" th:field="*{internal}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="endSem" id="endSem" th:field="*{endSem}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" th:field="*{grade}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="examDate" id="examDate" th:field="*{examDate}"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Please show the POST mapping for /exams/update/process

Comment: Also, your title says "bean name score", but the question says "bean name command"

Comment: "bean name command" is my typing mistake sorry for that , also I am getting this error when I hit "/exams/update" url. I think the post mapping does not have any roll until we submit the form.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So, you're getting that bind error just by loading the page, before you ever submit?

Comment: yes. When I hit the url "/exams/update" i am getting this error